# Binary Search Tree in O(log n)?

Tags: tree, binary-search-tree, computer-science, complexity-theory

Given a binary tree with n nodes, Is that possible to check whether the given tree is BST or not, in O(log n) time complexity?

Comment: I think this question is better suited for [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If n is the amount of nodes, then no, since you need to at least look at all the values once, so you'll need O(n) at least. But if you define n to be something special like the total amount of subtrees you could achieve this. (It is however a little stupid to do this, since it's kind of the same as saying you have more money if you have 100 cents instead of 1 euro. It might look more impressive but also weird and has no added value, it's just confusing to work with and normal people don't do this)

Here's the O(n) algorithm: if it is a BST then both the left and the right trees are BST in which all the values will be between a certain minimum and maximum value so you can create a recursive method that goes a little like this:

```
public boolean isBST(subtree, minvalue, maxvalue){
    root=root of subtree;
    if(root>maxvalue || root<minvalue) return false;
    if(has left child)
        if(!isBST(left-child-tree, minvalue, rootvalue)) return false;
    if(has right child)
        if(!isBST(right-child-tree, rootvalue, maxvalue)) return false;
    return true;
}
```

and you call this method with isBST(tree, -infinity, +infinity). This is pseudo-code and can of course be implemented better.

Comment: you can also see here for different versions of the O(n) algorithm: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/a-program-to-check-if-a-binary-tree-is-bst-or-not/